# google geocode api returns "zero results" in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps

When I put this URL in the browser, I get an answer: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=15838+Am%20Mellensee%20OT%20Mellensee+Hauptstra%C3%9Fe%2016

But in C# I get "zero results":
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=15838+Am%20Mellensee%20OT%20Mellensee+Hauptstra%C3%9Fe%2016");

earlier it works fine!
Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Put string address without encoding spaces and other special symbols like

```
var str = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=15838+Am Mellensee OT Mellensee+Hauptstra";
ds.ReadXml(str);
```

Comment: This was my first try. No success! But I find when I omit the 'OT ...' it works. But why works it in the browser URL? I think it is the same machine.